# How to move the Downloads folder (in Mountain Lion) to another disc

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I want the "Downloads" folder not on the system drive but on my second internal drive.

In Lion I just deleted the "Downloads" folder and replace it with an alias with the same name (pointing to the folder on the second drive ofc).

In ML I get ""Downloads" can't be modified or deleted because it's required by Mac OS X".

How to delete the folder? Can I change the permissions first to be able to delete it? 
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to do this from within the Terminal. Launch it from Applications → Utilities → Terminal.

1. Move the Downloads folder to your second drive, replacing `Data` (the name of my second drive) with whatever yours is called. You may be prompted for your OS X password.

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Downloads /Volumes/Data/Downloads
   ```
2. (Optional) Create a symlink to allow you to access your new Downloads folder in the old location. Again, replace `Data` with the name of your second drive.

   ```
   ln -s /Volumes/Data/Downloads ~/Downloads
   ```

This has just worked for me on OS X 10.8.1.

Comment: Only issue for me is that the symlink of "Movies" has a white, blank-page icon in the Finder even after a restart, while "Downloads" gets the right one

Comment: This solution works, but breaks the Cmd+Option+L shortcut. It goes to an empty, "broken" folder instead — e.g. Cmd+Up doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielSerodio use `chmod -h 700 ~/Downloads` to make the symlink's permissions equal to the old Downloads folder

Answer (score 3):

I'd encourage you not to mess with permissions.

You can create a new folder on the other drive (or use any other folder that you prefer) and use Safari preferences to set the new folder as the destination for  downloaded files to be placed.

Comment: The standard folders are proctected with ACLs so a simple chmod won't help here.

Comment: Forgot about that. I'll edit my answer, just keeping the advice and the *different* approach.

Comment: I've always just told apps to download to my Downloads folder on my 'data' drive.

Comment: It's a PITA doing it for everything though. There's always going to be another time you have to change it. In Windows you just right click, properties, change location. Then by default all programs download where you want them to. Surely there's a way on Mac..